# Ionic não reconhece meu css

Tags: javascript, css, ionic

Para ser bem claro, eu estou criando um app com `ionic 1.3` como aprendizado e estudo para a faculdade, e preciso usar um `css` e `js` externo. É uma `lib` chamada `Icheck` ([Link para o icheck](https://icheck.fronteed.com)). Já fiz teste com ela em outros projetos, e roda perfeitamente. Porém, não consigo utilizá-la com o `ionic`.
Li bastante gente falando sobre compilar com `sass` e tal usar o `gulp`, peguei até alguns exemplos de código para compilar, pois não conheço muito de `gulp`, `sass` ou frontend em geral kkkk.
 Parece estar tudo linkado certo e na ordem, porém não compila. Acredito que seja o `css`. Gostaria de uma ajuda sobre o que devo fazer para usar essa `lib` no `ionic` e o por que de simplesmente não colocar um link no `index` para funcionar?
Meu arquivo `index.html`, removi os outros arquivos `css` que o `gulp` injeta, mas é algo que não afeta o resto, já fiz o teste tanto com ele quanto sem eles.

```
  <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/_all.css">
  <!-- endinject -->
```

Meu arquivo `ionic.app.scss` está do jeito que veio, e acredito que aqui está a chave para o meu problema, mas até agora não consegui deslumbrar a solução.
Já tentei importar o `css` para que `gulp` gerasse um arquivo `ionic.app.css` com todos os `css` que precisava, mas acho que não funciona dessa forma.

```
/*
To customize the look and feel of Ionic, you can override the variables
in ionic's _variables.scss file.

For example, you might change some of the default colors:

$light:                           #fff !default;
$stable:                          #f8f8f8 !default;
$positive:                        #387ef5 !default;
$calm:                            #11c1f3 !default;
$balanced:                        #33cd5f !default;
$energized:                       #ffc900 !default;
$assertive:                       #ef473a !default;
$royal:                           #886aea !default;
$dark:                            #444 !default;
*/

// The path for our ionicons font files, relative to the built CSS in www/css
$ionicons-font-path: "../lib/ionic/fonts" !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";
```

Meu arquivo `Gulp.js` que fiz alguns testes para injetar automaticamente meu arquivo `.css` direto no meu `index`, o que funciona bem, porém não renderiza como deveria.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var bower = require('bower');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sh = require('shelljs');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss'], 
  javascript: [
  './www/**/*.js',
  '!./www/js/app.js',
  '!./www/lib/**'
  ],
  css: [
  './www/**/*.css', 
  '!./www/css/ionic.app*.css',
  '!./www/lib/**'
  ]
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass','index']);

gulp.task('index', function(){
 return gulp.src('./www/index.html')
 .pipe(inject(
   gulp.src(paths.javascript,
     {read: false}), {relative: true}))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'))
 .pipe(inject(
   gulp.src(paths.css,
     {read: false}), {relative: true}))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./www'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
  .pipe(sass())
  .on('error', sass.logError)
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/**'))
  .pipe(minifyCss({
    keepSpecialComments: 0
  }))
  .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/**'))
  .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch([
   paths.javascript,
   paths.css
   ], ['index']);
});

gulp.task('install', ['git-check'], function() {
  return bower.commands.install()
  .on('log', function(data) {
    gutil.log('bower', gutil.colors.cyan(data.id), data.message);
  });
});

gulp.task('git-check', function(done) {
  if (!sh.which('git')) {
    console.log(
      '  ' + gutil.colors.red('Git is not installed.'),
      '\n  Git, the version control system, is required to download Ionic.',
      '\n  Download git here:', gutil.colors.cyan('http://git-scm.com/downloads') + '.',
      '\n  Once git is installed, run \'' + gutil.colors.cyan('gulp install') + '\' again.'
      );
    process.exit(1);
  }
  done();
});
```

Segue uma imagem de como está a organização atual das minhas pastas e do meu arquivo onde faço os imports dos outros `css`, mas só para titulo de informação, já tentei linkar esses outros arquivos manualmente no `ionic` e não rodou também.
Acredito que não seja os arquivos `js`, pois estou usando outra `lib` e roda tranquilamente, mas para deixar claro essa `lib` faz uso de `jquery`.
[image: Ai como está a estutura das pasta e o meu arquivo _all.css]

Comment: Você está incluindo o css na index dentro de www ou dentro de templates?

Comment: dentro da index. na pasta template só tem as view login browser etc.

Comment: amigo o erro ocorre no simulador ou no device?

Answer (score -1):

Faça:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/line/_all.css">
```

Comment: Man esse arquivo ai não está dentro dessa pasta está dentro do diretório
css/
apasta css/line contem outro arquivos...

Answer (score -1):

Pelo o que conheço sobre `ionic`, ele usa de um arquivo `.css` próprio, que sobrepõe os outros na hora de compilar o código. Se encontrá-lo e tentar deletar o mesmo talvez o programa reconheça os códigos da forma que deveria